# ASP .Net Core Google Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, .net-core

I have a problem with google authentication on my .net core web api application.
My use case is simple, get bearer token from google put token in authorization header as "Bearer {token}" and call my web api.

But I cannot make it work. After I get token from google on following url:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=email%20openid&include_granted_scopes=true&state=some_test_state&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53512&response_type=token&client_id={someClientID}`

I will make call to my api with header:

```
Authorization: Bearer {TokenValue}
```

But every time I'm getting 401 Unauthorized.

This is my Startup class:

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Pull in any SDK configuration from Configuration object
    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());

    // Add S3 to the ASP.NET Core dependency injection framework.
    services.AddAWSService<Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3>();

    IocConfig.Configure(services);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddLambdaLogger(Configuration.GetLambdaLoggerOptions());

    var googleOptions = new GoogleOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
        ClientId = "clientid",
        ClientSecret = "cs",
        SignInScheme = "Google"
    };

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Did you every find the answer? I'm struggling myself.

Comment: Yes I wrote my own middleware.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your authentication scheme is "Google", but if you want to use bearer token you need to add it to your startup.cs

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddJwtBearer(options =>
           {
               // here's your options
           })
```

And use this authentication scheme instead of "Google"